# Celery is not waiting for the file write to complete

Tags: python, multithreading, celery

I created a celery task. The task has a list. For each element in list, I was calling some api. I used ThreadPoolExecutor to make these api calls concurrent. In each api call, I was appending the result in csv file. When the for loop completes, I was making a zip of that file. When I run this code without celery it works properly, but when I do using celery task, it gives the error as

> No file exist

at the line where I was making a zip. Please, explain why this is happening and how to solve this problem.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It was because of wrong input to celery task in args. Many online tutorials were using this format -

> add.apply_async(queue='low_priority', args=(10, 5))

while in args you have to pass a list of args. So the correct way is -

> add.apply_async(queue='low_priority', args=[10, 5])
> Here, is the reference from celery doc - https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/calling.html#example.